# Array of ImageViews what's wrong?

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity, imageview

I've an Activity with 20 ImageViews named level0...level20. I want change image source for first 10 ImageViews. I tried this, but no good results. plase help me.

```
private ImageView [] lvlImgs;
private int unlocked=10;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.levels);      
  for(int i=0;i<unlocked;i++)
  { 
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("level"+i, "id", this.getPackageName());
    lvlImgs[i]=(ImageView)findViewById(id);
    lvlImgs[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image_to_show);  
  }      
}
```

Comment: What happens? Does `findViewById(id)` return null and you get a NullPointerException on the next line?

Answer (score 0):

You should post your `Exception` or Error also.

Considering your posted code, the reason I can understand is

you are not initializing your `lvlImgs` array as it should be:

```
lvlImgs = new ImageView [unlocked];
```

This may be a reason for application crash.

Posting your `Exception` log-cat may help us to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer. I found other way for that: use a GridView and an ImageAdapter class. For those interested:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private int unlocked=10;
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return 20;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90, 50));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
           } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    if(position<unlocked){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gheta_med);
    }else{
         imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gheta_med_lock);
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

and in my activity

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
   gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
   gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                Log.i("item", ""+arg2);
```